# Turning off log messages in Java Logging Framwork

Tags: java, logging

I am looking for a way to turn off specific level of log messages when I run the application. For example, if a pass `debug` parameter to my application, the log messages with `Level.INFO` should be shown but otherwise they should not. However, the log message with `SEVERE` level should still be displayed. Is there a way to do it without using `IF/ELSE` statements?  Thanks

I am using Java Logging Framework like this:

```
logger.log(Level.INFO, "The piece is in the pending queue");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is a `Logger` object named logger following method can be used to set the level of a particular object:

```
logger.setLevel(<level>)
```

But if you have multiple logger objects in a project and you want to set the level for all of them you can use the following:

```
Handler[] handlers
            = Logger.getLogger("").getHandlers();
    for (int index = 0; index < handlers.length; index++) {
        handlers[index].setLevel(<level>);
    }
```

Where these are the levels as Hichamov has stated

- SEVERE (highest value)
- WARNING
- INFO
- CONFIG
- FINE
- FINER
- FINEST (lowest value)

Answer (score 3):

[Click here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-logging/configuration.html) to find out configuring log.

Answer (score 1):

You set log level by `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=<level>` where level stands for:

- SEVERE (highest value)
- WARNING
- INFO
- CONFIG
- FINE
- FINER
- FINEST (lowest value)

You need to treat the levels like a stack : You define where you stand and the framework write logs dependently on the severity you chosen. For example, if you set level to `INFO` you'll get logs of severity `SEVERE`, `WARNING` and `INFO`